# Draw Pieslice in Turbo Pascal

Tags: graphics, pascal, pie-chart

I really confused with parameters StartAngle and EndAngle, how it works.
For example I need to draw arc from -30 to 30.
I tried:

```
(-30,30),
(330,30),
(30,330),
(330,390),
(-30,390) 
etc.
```

But every one draws full circle minus desired `(-30,30)` sector. 
While `piesclice(...330,360...)` and `piesclice(...360,390)` works as I need, giving together desired `(-30,30)` sector.

However I want proper algorithm of work with pieslice to draw arcs `<180` and `>180` in desired direction. 
No manual expanded on this subject. 
Please help me.

It can draw sector from 0 to 30, but when I try draw from -30 to 30
it draws full circle minus sector i.e. more than 180 degrees arc
I tried to pass 330, 390

Comment: From Turbo Pascal help: `The angles for Arc, Ellipse, FillEllipse, PieSlice, and Sector are counter-clock-wise with 0 degrees at 3 o'clock, 90 degrees at 12 o'clock, and so on.`

Comment: Please add code to show what you have already tried. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more on how to ask a good stackoverflow question

Comment: Negative angels cannot be passed: `procedure PieSlice(X, Y: Integer; StAngle, EndAngle, Radius: Word);`

Comment: Seems there is error in Graph: Arc(330, 30) works properly, while Sector and Pieslice in this case draw large sector

Comment: @LU RD 
> Negative angels cannot be passed.
ok, I tried to simulate 30 with 330=360-30
still can't understand how it choose direction to draw sector

Comment: @MBo
> Seems there is error in Graph  
It's pitty. No way to bypass it?
I tried to draw PacMan oriented left, right, up and down

Comment: I'm afraid you need to make own procedure drawing two slices together in case of (start>end)

Comment: Thanks to everybody
I solved problem with arc and floodfill

Comment: @LURD: Angels are generally very positive and helpful. ;-)

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, depends on what angle you are looking from :-)

Comment: Fallen angels, OTOH, are generally negative and vicious. ;-)

Comment: Found solution: sector (draws elliptic sector)